# Defining the convergence of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

When determining the convergence of a sequence $\left \{S_n \right \}$, it is always defined as, if the limit, $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$ exists and is non-infinite, then the sequence converges, else it diverges, my question is, why is it defined that way, is it to prevent infinities in the set of numbers that defines the sequence? For example if I use a sequence of the form $$\left\{\frac{1}{\left(n-2\right)\left(n-3\right)}\right\}$$ then there are still infinite numbers within the boundaries of the sequence, why would I limit myself to checking the sequence at infinite values of $n$?

Comment: What do you mean by infinite values? Infinity is not a real number.

Comment: yes, I completely understand that, I mean, what is the purpose of defining the convergence and/or divergence of the sequence that way? I don't see the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the limit of a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is equal to $L$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find a point in the sequence after which all further elements of the sequence are at most $\epsilon$ away from $L$, or more succinctly put:

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \; \exists N : \forall m > N \; |a_m-L| < \epsilon$$

Roughly speaking, elements of the sequence get closer and closer to a number $L$ as you look at elements with higher and higher indices.

There is an additional definition that the limit of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ tends to infinity if for any $K$ you can find a point in the sequence after which all further elements of the sequence are larger than $K$, or more succinctly put:

$$\forall K \; \exists N : \forall m > N \; a_m > K$$

This is different from the sequence grouping up next to a number, but if you were to imagine a number greater than all natural numbers called infinity and perhaps pick a different metric than Euclidean distance (the absolute value in the first definition), then you could perhaps combine these two definitions into a single definition for a limit. But there is no such number called infinity in the real numbers, so you can't do this. The second definition is merely a convenient way to refer to certain sequences that keep growing.

Convergent series are series that group up next to one particular number. Divergent series can oscillate between two values, grow without bound, or hop around in no discernable order.

Now as for your example, $\frac{1}{(n-2)(n-3)}$ is undefined for $n=2,3$, not infinite, but even if you had a number system in which infinity was a thing and defined the sequence to have a value of infinity for $n=2,3$, that wouldn't change the fact that the sequence gets closer and closer to $0$ as you look at higher and higher indicies (i.e. its limit is $0$).